# Save all objects/control/text as image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a photo editor in ASP.Net (Adding text, dragging of clip arts in the image, etc.). My problem is how to save the artwork as 1 image.

[image]

What is the easiest way to save the artwork as image, is it possible to use panel?

Comment: I'd record each element and it's position/orientation in the page and create the image with System.Drawing

Comment: Can you show how do you implement that? Thanks

Comment: I can't do a full example at the moment but this is the area you need to be looking in - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx you're going to need to split this into much spaller chunks to solve it

Comment: You post back the position of each graphics, and re-create it on code behind...

Comment: Where are you drawing that image?Post some code.

Comment: @techno: Actually, I dont have any codes yet, I am researching what is the best and easiest way how to save the image.

Comment: @Aristos: Do you have a snippet about this?

Comment: @MMakati No I do not have, but the client side is easy, just read the position and place it on a post back input, then on code behind you find one of so many libraries that do the job, one that I just found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93081/ASP-NET-Generating-Images-on-the-Fly